# Odoo computed field Year from date_invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I extract only the year from a date field (x_date_invoice) to a new computed odoo field for example x_jaar

I am using Odoo 10.
[image: FIeld x_jaar info]
[image: Field x_date_invoice info]

Comment: hello Pelingier, doing import datetime file?

Comment: first import this below,

Comment: (1)from datetime import datetime
 (2)import time

Comment: ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in u'from datetime import datetime \nimport time\nfor record in self:\n    record[\'x_jaar\'] = str(datetime.strptime(record[\'x_date_invoice\'],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y"))'   (error that i receive)

Comment: can you please paste code here?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime  (line 1)
import time (line 2)
for record in self: (line 3)
 record['x_jaar'] = str(datetime.strptime(record['x_date_invoice'],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y"))` (line 4)

Comment: Any your mistake because this code perfectly run in my side.

Comment: Please check which types date you get in record['x_date_invoice']

Comment: The value of the field record['x_date_invoice'] 
is from the related field  invoice_id.date_invoice and the field type = date, The model i am working in is account.invoice.line

Comment: I adjusted the question with new codes and screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello Pelingier,**

Basic Function of Python,

## strptime()

**Description**
The method strptime() parses a string representing a time according to a format. The return value is a struct_time as returned by gmtime() or localtime().

The format parameter uses the same directives as those used by strftime(); it defaults to "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y" which matches the formatting returned by ctime().

If string cannot be parsed according to format, or if it has excess data after parsing, ValueError is raised.

**Syntax**
Following is the syntax for strptime() method:

```
time.strptime(string[, format])
```

**Parameters**
**string** -- This is the time in string format which would be parsed based on the given format.
**format** -- This is the directive which would be used to parse the given string.

## strftime()

**Description**
The method strftime() converts a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a string as specified by the format argument.

If t is not provided, the current time as returned by localtime() is used. format must be a string. An exception ValueError is raised if any field in t is outside of the allowed range.

**Syntax**
Following is the syntax for strftime() method:

```
time.strftime(format[, t])
```

**Parameters**
**t** -- This is the time in number of seconds to be formatted.
**format** -- This is the directive which would be used to format given time. The following directives can be embedded in the format string:

==========================================================================

## Your Question Solution

The first import library is from `datetime import datetime` after use all the functionality of the DateTime.

Try below code,

```
for record in self:
    record['x_jaar'] = str(datetime.strptime(record['x_date_invoice'],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y"))
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comments, please.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion I tried your answer but receive the following error. Please look at the adjusted question. Thx Peter

Answer (score 1):

fields.Datetime and fields.Date are storaged as string, so yo have to parse into a python datetime. Then you can extract the year.

```
datetime.strptime(your_datetime, your_datetime_format).year
```

Answer (score 0):

In **odoo**, datetime is imported using :

`import datetime`

Not the usual way:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

That said, you should use this code:

```
str(datetime.datetime.strptime(record['x_date_invoice'],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y"))
```

Comment: I tried your answer but receive the following error (AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime')

Comment: so we should import datetime using : (from datetime import datetime) not (import datetime)

Answer (score 0):

`date_invoice` field value is a string and to get the year you will need to parse it using for example the `datetime` which is available in the evaluation context.

You can check the help under `How to define a computed field` section after the `Compute` field

> The only predefined variables are
>     `self` (the set of records to compute)
>     `datetime` (Python module)
>     `dateutil` (Python module)
>     `time` (Python module)
> Other features are accessible through `self`, like `self.env`, etc.

***Example:***

```py
for record in self:
    record['x_jaar'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(record.date_invoice, "%Y-%m-%d").year
```

Since Odoo 12 Dates and Datetimes are objects, to get the year just use the `year` attribute:

***Example:***

```py
for record in self:
    if record.date_invoice:
        record['x_jaar'] = record.date_invoice.year
```

Answer (score 0):

Being new to python, had to try all suggestions mentioned here but couldn't get it to work. After several trials and errors, in odoo 14, below code worked for me (in the computed field section) - hope this helps somebody.

for record in self:
record['x_studio_maand'] = record.x_studio_date_start.strftime("%B %Y")
#get month and year from a datetime field